# Using hist function

Tags: pandas

I have a csv files with a table of info, I need to plot a hist with the information available, the table has dates and numbers, I want the dates to be on the x axis and the numbers on the y axis, but it is plotting the other way around, below are the details:

The below table is on a csv file (called Results.csv in the below code) that I am reading from, so it has 3 columns, index, Date, and Incidents

```
    Date    Incidents
0   14-06-17    637
1   15-06-17    549
2   16-06-17    510
3   17-06-17    460
4   18-06-17    431
5   19-06-17    332
6   20-06-17    220
```

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Results_Hist = pd.read_csv ("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Results.csv")
hist = Results_Hist['Incidents'].hist()
```

[image: And here is the plot I am getting]

Please keep in mind that I still want to have it vertical, so again, the dates on the bottom, and the values on the y axis

Also, I don't know why the dates are changing to numbers from 0 to 2
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ali, what you want is not a *histogram* but rather a *bar-chart*. Histogram will collapse similar values to a single bin, showing you the frequency on the y-axis (that is why you see most of your value with frequency 1, and only one bin contains 2 observations) while - as I understood from your description - you want to display a value for each day separately, right?

If so, do this:

```
Results_Hist.plot(x='Date', y='AIncidents', kind='bar')
```

Find more kinds of plot [in Pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html).

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I wanted, thanks, I just thought it is called Histogram

Answer (score 0):

what you describe ( if i get it right a plot w/ dates vs incidents) is not a histogram. a 1d histogram only shows the distribution of single variable.

you can use a bar plot for your purpose

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# build sample data
dates = pd.date_range(start='01-01-1990', end='01-07-1990')
incidents = np.random.normal(loc=100, scale=10, size=len(dates))
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(dates, incidents), columns=['Dates', 'Incidents'])
print(df)
```

output:

```
       Dates   Incidents
0 1990-01-01   89.619541
1 1990-01-02  102.241335
2 1990-01-03   81.212102
3 1990-01-04   90.795959
4 1990-01-05   99.832007
5 1990-01-06   86.111749
6 1990-01-07  104.189885


# plot incidents vs days
plt.bar(
        x=df.Dates,
        height=df.Incidents
)
plt.show()
```

which yields

[image]